# Switching backlight to RGB in the following monitor C24FG70

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, rgb, backlight, apa102

I have the following monitor: Samsung C24FG70. Is it possible to change the white led backlights with RGB leds? Possibly the smd [APA102](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/APA102.pdf) with the following microcontroller: [ESP8266](http://download.arduino.org/products/UNOWIFI/0A-ESP8266-Datasheet-EN-v4.3.pdf). How could i hook this into the current LCD controller board? any input is appreciated.

The leds operate at 5v .2 watts. I can have a separate five volt power supply for them. and run the data and clock to them from the ESP8266. just not sure how the works the the LCD controller.

Any input is appreciated. Where could i get the current schematic for the board that is in the Samsung  C24FG70?

Answer (score 0):

LED lighting is done inside the LCD panel ([Example](http://www.datadisplay-group.com/fileadmin/pdf/produkte/Displays/LG/LM230WF3-SLD1_Datasheet.pdf) p.13 Fig.5), not in the monitor. So it's not possible (or easy) to directly access to the backlight module.

To enlighten the whole rectangle panel, high-current LED strips *(e.g. 125mA)* are positioned across the edges of the glass. Those LEDs are also very low-profile like [this one](http://neonica.eu/media/products/d5bea1c09d8f0dd2fa15e3ec573a9016/images/thumbnail/large_e5-300-24v-logo-osram.jpg?lm=1468485087).

So, RGB LEDs you've suggested don't have that high power to enlighten the whole glass (even if you use 50 of them).